# Download File and Limit Rate with Python

Tags: python, file, download, limit, rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Throttling with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456649/throttling-with-urllib2)

How do I download a file and limit the rate?

I'm looking for functionality similar to `wget --limit-rate`, and currently, I'm using `urlretrieve`.

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://example.com/somebigfile.zip", "bigfile.zip") # how to limit-rate?
```

Comment: That answered my question, marcog..thanks!