# How to limit download rate of HTTP requests in requests python library?

Tags: python, http, httprequest, wget, python-requests

Is it possible to limit the download rate of GET requests using the `requests` Python library? For instance, with a command like this:

```
r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

...is it possible to limit the download rate? I'm hoping for something similar to this `wget` command:

```
wget --limit-rate=20k https://stackoverflow.com/
```

I know it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456649/throttling-with-urllib2) with `urllib2`. I'm asking specifically about the `requests` library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several approaches to rate limiting; one of them is [token bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket), for which you can find [a recipe here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511490-implementation-of-the-token-bucket-algorithm/) and [another one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667508/whats-a-good-rate-limiting-algorithm).

Usually you would want to do throttling or rate limiting on `socket.send()` and `socket.recv()`. You could play with [`socket-throttle`](https://github.com/minkustree/socket-throttle) and see if it does what you need.

---

This is not to be confused with [`x-ratelimit` rate limiting response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022624/examples-of-http-api-rate-limiting-http-response-headers), which are related to a number of requests rather than a download / transfer rate.

Comment: Since the OP asked about doing this with the `requests` library, this doesn't really answer the question... except that you are suggesting he re-write deep portions of `requests` to do what he wants.

Comment: @DanH, you are more than welcome to provide a better answer, at time of writing the answer was "no, unless you mess with the internals", which isn't helpful to OP.

Answer (score 3):

No built-in support but, it is possible to use stream api.

```py
>>> import requests
>>> import time
>>> req = requests.request('GET', 'https://httpbin.org/get', stream=True)
>>> for data in req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
...     time.sleep(0.001)
...
```

In [advanced usage](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#blocking-or-non-blocking) there is written that its's allow you to retrieve smaller quantities of the response at a time.

In my network the example above (leading to a several GB large file) without sleep had bandwidth 17.4 MB/s and with sleep 1 ms 2.5 MB/s.