# Python - urllib and urllib2 - What happens if you don't read?

Tags: python, download, urllib2, urllib

I want to implement a download speed limit with urllib/urllib2. The basic idea is to look at how much was downloaded in the past x seconds and if it is above the limit, the script simply sleeps for some time.

Now the question is, what happens if you have an open connection (with `urlopen()`), but don't call the `read()` function for a while?

1. Does urllib have a built-in buffer that downloads until the buffer is full and every time you call `read()`, the buffer is reduced by n bytes and the download continues (and obviously if it is full, urllib waits)?
2. If there is a urllib buffer, how big is it, and can one set the size manually?
3. If there is no buffer, does urllib simply continue to download?
4. Is there a difference between urllib and urllib2 `read()` function or are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

I wholeheartedly recommend using the excellent [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) library instead of urllib or urllib2.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346158/python-requests-how-to-limit-received-size-transfer-rate-and-or-total-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691231/how-to-limit-download-rate-of-http-requests-in-requests-python-library) for how others went about implementing transfer rate limiting.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at requests and the links you sent. But even with requests, the question remains what will happen if request.iter_content(1024) is not called for a while, does requests continue downloading or pausing?

Comment: I think when you use `requests`' streaming, the download pauses until you ask for the next chunk. The reason I think so is because I once used this trick to limit the amount of memory a large downloading was using. And when you set `stream=True` in the call to `requests.get` then your connection will not get returned to the pool until all the data was consumed, or you close it yourself. See if this [guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) helps. And don't forget to `if chunk is not None: #do stuff` - chunks that are `None` are just keep-alives.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll do a network analysis to see how much data my scripts consumes, just to make sure that request actually pauses.

Comment: Cool, let me know your findings!