# Limit download speed in pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, pytube

I made a youtube to mp3 converter using pytube and I was wondering whether I could set a download speed limit through my own code or by editing the pytube library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691231/how-to-limit-download-rate-of-http-requests-in-requests-python-library)